# MySQL Query Join 2 tables with 2 relationship tables

Tags: mysql

I have a real mindbender of a MySQL problem which I am now thinking there is no answer to. Please help me, you are my only hope!

Stripping it down to the basics, I have two tables, "People" and "Activity". It is possible (long story and lots of data involved) for these two tables to be joined by two different relationship tables: people_activity and entity_activity
I need to do a query on the activity table which gets the people record/s linked to activity records based on both relationship tables.

This is what I have, but it is massively slow on lots of data:

```
select * from activity 
left join peopleactivity on peopleactivity.activityid = activity.activityid
left join entityactivity on entityactivity.activityid = activity.activityid
left join people on (peopleactivity.peopleid = people.peopleid OR
                     entityactivity.entityid = people.peopleid)
```

Some more notes - I have also tried creating a view to combine the results of the two relationship tables and instead joining people and activity via this view. This also works, but is also still massively slow

Changing how the relationship/s work to consolodate to one table is a major headache

I have also tried a union -like this -

```
select * from activity 
left join peopleactivity on peopleactivity.activityid = activity.activityid
left join people on (peopleactivity.peopleid = people.peopleid) 
union
select * from activity 
left join peopleactivity on peopleactivity.activityid = activity.activityid
left join people on (entityactivity.entityid= people.peopleid)
```

which also works, but for other reasons causes me problems. I really need to do this in one query without changing too much underlying.

Has anyone got any super amazing ideas that I have missed??!

Comment: In that second query (the UNION) it looks like you are UNIONing two identical queries. I'm thinking one of those should involve the `entityactivity` table rather than the `peopleactivity` table. Also, the `UNION ALL` operator can have some significant performance advantages over the `UNION` operator.

Comment: What is the performance of each separate query like? Is each one "massively slow" or are they separately "blazingly fast"? An EXPLAIN on each query, and on the combined query would answer questions like what indexes are being used. Sometimes two separate queries is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. I had tried various incarnations of the above. My answer was to set up a new table, copy all the existing links into that table, and then use triggers to add/remove links to that table whenever the links were added removed in the two separate link tables. This works well and also allows me to use indexes on this new table to keep things nice and snappy. Many thanks for those that took the time to post the ideas though!

Answer (score 0):

You may try to replace `OR` with `IN`

```
left join people on people.peopleid IN (peopleactivity.peopleid, entityactivity.entityid)
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) Try setting the id of the tables as the primary key on each table

2.) Use inner joins instead of left joins. Not sure why you are using left joins here as you will get all the results of the other tables left joined on the activity table and get basically all records whether or not they have a join value in another table. I think this might also help you. Can you post a describe of your tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should keep the `UNION` query but making those `INNER` joins. Do you really need `LEFT` joins?

You could also change it into `UNION ALL`, which will have some performance gain:

```
SELECT activity.*, people.*, 'PA' AS joining_table 
  FROM activity 
    JOIN peopleactivity ON peopleactivity.activityid = activity.activityid
    JOIN people ON peopleactivity.peopleid = people.peopleid
UNION ALL
SELECT activity.*, people.*, 'EA'
  FROM activity 
    JOIN entityactivity ON entityactivity.activityid = activity.activityid
    JOIN people ON entityactivity.entityid = people.peopleid
```